# how do 4k or 1080 images look like on a 720p monitor?

Tags: video-quality

I try to display higher resolution images (2400x1600) on my smaller 1366x768 monitor. I've noticed in 'normal view' (without zoom), it looks like *some details are washed out*, however when I zoom into a certain extent I notice that these details appear very clearly.

I believe that there are missing pixels, which not displayed properly on my monitor because of the difference between the pixel scale of the image and the monitor...

Would this 2400x1600 image look better on a monitor of the same pixel scale?

Thanks in advance to all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When displaying an image whose pixel sizes are larger than your monitor, you loose some information and your graphic card is doing some processing to fit the large image in a smaller screen. You will get the best result when watching the image on a monitor whose native pixel sizes are equal to the image pixel sizes.